# Are $f, g : X → S^n$ still homotopic when they are allowed to be antipodal?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $f, g : X → S^n$ are never antipodal, the homotopy map can be constructed as $$H(x,t)=\frac{(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)}{\|(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)\|}.$$

I wonder the following statement is still true:

> Let $f, g : X → S^n$ be continuous functions such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ **are allowed to be antipodal** (i.e. $f(x)=−g(x)$ for some $x ∈ X$), then $f,g$ are still homotopic.

If it is still true(at least I believe so), then we need to construct an explicit homotopy(I can imagine a homotopy map that goes through a geodesic curve on the sphere from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$, but I can't find a way to write it down explicitly).

If it is not true, then we need to prove the following:

> > Let $f, g : X → S^n$ be homotopic continuous functions, then $f(x)\ne −g(x)$ for any $x ∈ X$.

Any solution or reference will be appreciated!

Comment: Would you really think that the space of homotopy classes from $X$ to a sphere are always trivial? I guess you may know that $\pi_1(S^1)=[S^1,S^1]$ is non-trivial and contain at least 2 elements. The second assumption is also false; it is not a problem to homotop any function $f$ to another $\tilde{f}$ such that  $\tilde{f}(x)=-g(x)$ in one point $x$.

Comment: @PeterFranek Thank you and +1! But I don't understand your second sentence. What do you mean by "it is not a problem to homotop any function ......"

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then $f(x)$ can very well be $g(-x)$ in one point $x$; moreover, you can choose any $x$ and any $y\in S^n$ and replace $f$ by a function $\tilde{f}$ homotopic to $f$ and $g$, such that $\tilde{f}$ equals $f$ everywhere except on an arbitrary small neighborhood of $x$, and $\tilde{f}(x)=y$.

Comment: @PeterFranek It is still hard for me to understand your comment. But i think I know why my second statement is wrong by an easy example. Let $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ such that $f=(0,1), g=(0,-1)$, then $f$ and $g$ are both homotopic and antipodal.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the two statements is true.

Take the identity $\operatorname{id} : S^n \to S^n$, and a constant map $f : S^n \to S^n$ given by $f(x) = x_0$ for a fixed $x_0 \in S^n$. Then $\operatorname{id}$ and $f$ are not homotopic (the sphere $S^n$ is not contractible), and indeed they are antipodal at some point since $f(-x_0) = x_0 = - \operatorname{id}(-x_0)$.

(In fact as this argument shows, the only spaces $Z$ such that all maps $X \to Z$ are homotopic are either contractible or empty.)

Now fix again some $x_0 \in S^n$, and let $f(x) = x_0$ and $g(x) = -x_0$. Then we have $f(x) = -g(x)$ for all $x$ (not even just a single one), but $f$ and $g$ are still homotopic (simply choose a path between $x_0$ and $-x_0$ to find the homotopy).